# How is the triangle inequality used to derive this inequality?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

I am trying to prove that any non-constant complex polynomial tends to infinity as z goes to infinity. Someone asked this question on this website [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232009/complex-polynimial-tends-to-infinity). In that question, the following hint is given:
$\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}$
$$ \abs{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k} \ge \abs{a_n}\abs{z}^n - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\abs{a_k}\abs z^k $$

They say that this is a consequence of the triangle inequality, but I am not seeing how. Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|} |a_nz^n|=  \abs{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kz^k}\leq \abs{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k}+\abs{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{a_k}z^k} \leq \abs{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\abs{a_k}\abs{z^k} $$

Answer (score 1):

$$\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}|a_nz^n|=  \abs{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kz^k}\leq \abs{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k z^k}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\abs{a_k}\abs z^k $$

Comment: Small typo --- $z_n$ meant to be $z^n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson ty

Answer (score 0):

The general idea here is to "reverse" the triangle inequality by adding and subtracting terms. In particular, 
$$ |x| = |x + y - y| \le |x + y| + |y|$$
which implies
$$ |x| - |y| \le |x + y|$$
See if you can insert appropriate quantities for $x,y$ to apply this "reverse" triangle inequality to your problem.